# Google Maps not showing actual location

Tags: gps, google-maps

Google Maps is not showing my actual location. It shows me as being nearby (almost a kilometer away). What can the problem?

Comment: Did you enable GPS?

Comment: Please give us more info. Check whether your GPS is turned on. Try uninstalling and reinstalling the app. (sky should be vibile for a GPS to work properly). Try these suggestions.

Comment: How much time do you give it to synchronize? It can often take a number of minutes. Do you have good network connectivity where you are?

Comment: A tool like [GPS Status & Toolbox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.eclipsim.gpsstatus2) might be helpful in ensuring your GPS is functioning well.

Comment: GPS was turned on and i always wait long time for complete loading.

Answer (score 7):

There are a number of possible reasons for an inaccurate location, mostly relating to the lack of a good GPS fix. If the phone cannot get an accurate GPS fix, it will use more approximate methods of deriving its location - such as cell tower locations and wifi hotspot locations.

Possible reasons for no good GPS fix, in vague descending order of likliness:

1. You are indoors, or the sky is otherwise obstructed (trees can have quite an impact)
2. GPS is turned off or disabled on your phone, or you are using Google Maps on a device that does not have a GPS receiver.
3. You haven't used the GPS for a day or more, or you have moved a long way since you last used it, and it is taking a while to get a fix - this can take a minute or more in some circumstances, especially if you don't have a data signal.
4. The GPS isn't working properly. Some phones have GPS trouble occasionally and require a restart.
5. There is interference with the GPS - e.g. naval forces sometimes conduct exercises with GPS jamming, and I've had... variable results trying to use it near a large naval base before.

Normally if Google Maps can only give an approximate fix it will show a circle around your position, showing uncertainty. It might help with diagnosis to know whether you are seeing this circle, as that will indicate whether Maps knows that it has an approximate location or whether it thinks that it has an accurate one and is wrong.

Comment: GPS device is still on, and i got the value for latitude & longitude from my smartphone its is actual one when i check google map in my PC but the problem is, In my application i want to point the actual location with pointer that pointer not point actual location still the GPS on.